# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' inside SpringContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, scala, maven, spring-mvc

I am invoking a spring bean from a java class, and is calling that java class from a scala program. I have packeged my program inside a jar using maven and is exploding the spring dependency inside it. But when calling the bean it is throwing the falling exception-

```
> User class threw exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0
> in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in
> stage 5.0 (TID 6, hostname03):
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Line 6 in XML document from URL
> [jar:file:/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/filecache/101/SomeJar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-job.jar!/SpringContext.xml]
> is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
> lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 122; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
> declaration of element 'beans'. at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
```

My SpringContext.xml looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:RuleSpringContext.xml" />
<bean id="serviceImpl" class="com.org.name.services.dao.ServiceImpl" /> 

    <bean id="contextInitializer" class="com.org.name.services.config.AppContextInitializer" />

</beans>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Also when I am running the program from eclipse bean is getting invoked its just that when I am running my jar the issue is coming. I am using spark-submit to run the jar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems xml xsi:schemaLocation declaration wrong.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-[version].xsd
```

Replace the [version] with appropriate spring version you are using.

Comment: Spring schemas getting loaded from jar file, make sure you have proper jars in classpath, and extract the spring-beans jar you will find the all the xsds under beans/factory/xml package.

Comment: yes all the xsds are there, and I am exploding my jars.